# Double processing after context menu click

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that inserts text into textarea and similar.

The user can choose text from the popup or the contextmenu.

I have  "all_frames" : true so that my content script can see all the iframes - in case a textarea is in an iframe.

After a save to the database (more on this in a bit), if the user uses the contextmenu to add text (handled via messaging from background.js to content.js) to a text area the text is added twice.

If the user uses the popup.html mechanism, which passes text to the same content.js, the text is only entered once (the desired outcomes!).

The message is only passed once by background.js.

For instance, if there are five iframes on a page, and therefore 5 instances of content.js, the contextmenu listener script runs 10 times (not 5, as it should).

If I remove "all_frames" : true from the manifest then the text only adds once.

But I need to keep this setting so I can reach textareas in iFrames. And the popup insert works beautifully everywhere.

The save to the database is what triggers the behavior - and that process is a simple json write to a php file. I wipe the contextmenu as part of that process - but again, it isn't a question of the background.js sending 2 messages. One message is sent, and for some reason the code runs through the messaging routine 2x.

I've tried creating flags to mark once a single successful insertion has happened, but everything is asynch and I don't think this would be helpful even if I could get it to work in some cases.

I feel like I need to kill some old content.js processes or something...

The kicker: **if I Reload** the Extension (in developer mode) the contextmenu works properly and inserts selected text only once. It's only after I save to the db that the problem occurs.

I'm very close to throwing out contextmenus as a feature and just using the elegant popup.html. But this seems like some weird edge case that would be worth understanding.

Many thanks for taking a look. I've included some code and also a screenshot of the console showing the 10x repeats of the content.js code when inserting into a Google Doc.

**background.js**

```
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {method: "insertComment", comment: tempText}, function(response) {
        // console.log(response.status);
    });
});
```

**content.js**

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
      function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            if (request.method == 'insertComment'){
              var sValue = request.comment;
              var currentEltag = document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase();      //Checking for currently selected area
console.log("currentEltag before logic: " + currentEltag + " / id: " + document.activeElement.id);
          console.log("activeTag: " + activeTag);
          // console.log("activeEl: " + activeEl.id + ' / name: ' + activeEl.name + ' /value: ' + activeEl.value);

          if (activeTag === undefined || activeTag === null){
            console.log('currentEltag in logic: ' + currentEltag);
            if (currentEltag === 'iframe'){
              activeTag = 'iframe';
              console.log('Making activeTag equal iframe');
            }
          }

          var sField = activeEl;

          if (activeTag === 'input' || activeTag === 'textarea'){
            console.log('Dealing with plain input/textarea - yes! sField is: ' + sField);

            var nStart = sField.selectionStart;
            var nEnd = sField.selectionEnd;

             if (nStart || nEnd == '0'){
                console.log("Inside insert sub with starting point: " + nStart + ' and end ' + nEnd + ' with value ' + sValue);
                  console.log('Print and increment...');
                  sField.value = sField.value.substring(0, nStart) + sValue + sField.value.substring(nEnd, sField.value.length);
                  sField.selectionStart = nStart + sValue.length;
                  sField.selectionEnd = nStart + sValue.length;
                  console.log('Printed value1...and flag is now: ');
                  chrome.storage.sync.get("flag", function(data) {
                  console.log("Flag", data.flag);
                  });
              }
              else {
                sField.value = sValue;
                 console.log('Printed value2...');
              }
          }   //End if input or textarea
```

[image]

Comment: How do content scripts get "old" in your extension? Do you inject new ones? The code provided in the question is not sufficient to pinpoint the cause. Anyway, such weird issues are usually quite easy to "bisect" using the primary tool: the devtools debugger. You can also mix in divide-and-conquer approach: comment/uncomment parts of the code until you locate the actual problem area.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look...

Comment: Thank you for taking a look.

I have been trying to eliminate reasons...the code is running the same path, though - both background.js (for the contextmenu) and popup.js (for inserting from the popup) send a message to the same context.js file.

By 'old' I was just throwing out a hunch - it's like there is a ghost or duplicate of the content.js files remaining.

Comment: If you notice in the console, the first time the text is inserted it's placed at location 0. The second time the code realizes there is text in place and puts the text starting at character 21. So the code inserts text, then sees the text it has inserted, then re-inserts the same text.

Comment: Okay...I was kind of right: the duplication only happens when I keep another of my Extension's pages OPEN. And if I have 3 pages (account, edit, whatever) open, I get 4x inserted comments. But only from the context menu...the console.log of my other Extension pages even has logging showing that the Extension is trying to insert text...

I guess this is because background.js is running on every open page...but I don't know how to limit...I would have thought the messaging targeted only a specific page...

Comment: `I guess this is because background.js is running on every open page` Why would you run it on every page? See the extension architecture overview: the background page is a *separate* page (like a hidden browser tab) with its own context/DOM.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thank you for the help...yes, I had somehow left the basic architecture behind and was referencing background.js from my various html pages. Once I got rid of those references (and those pages can still access background.js, obviously) the duplication went away. Easy way to burn a day...:) I had tried all kinds of crazy stuff. 

So you did answer the question - if you want to make your last comment an answer I'll mark it correct.